# Paste particular cells (ordered) of all rows of a table

Tags: r, string, row, paste, rules

I have a table which looks like this:

```
example <- read.table(text ="
   Nr orderedNr Type   TextA  TextB Year       Date
1  469         1    A  Text2 Text12 2012 01.01.2015
2  470         8    C  Text9 Text19 1961 08.01.2015
3  471         2    A  Text3 Text13 2012 02.01.2015
4  472         9    C Text10 Text20 1947 09.01.2015
5  474         3    B  Text4 Text14 2005 03.01.2015
6  622         5    A  Text6 Text16 1993 05.01.2015
7  623         6    B  Text7 Text17 2009 06.01.2015
8  624         7    B  Text8 Text18 1964 07.01.2015
9  625         4    C  Text5 Text15 2009 04.01.2015
10 626        10    A Text11 Text21 1988 10.01.2015
")
```

By this I can paste all rows:

```
rows <- apply(table, 1, paste, collapse=", ")
```

But they have to be ordered by orderedNr and I don't need all colums/cells of one row and need them in a special order.

The rules in which order the cells of one row should be printed are determined by the type of row. For example:

```
type A: orderedNr, TextA, TextB, Year, Date
type B: orderedNr, TextB, TextA, Year, Date
type C: orderedNr, Year, TextB, TextA, Date
```

My output should look like this:

```
1, Text2, Text12, 2012, 01.01.2015
2, Text3, Text13, 2012, 02.01.2015
3, Text14, Text4, 2005, 03.01.2015
4, 2009, Text15, Text5, 04.01.2015
```

... and so on.

Hopefully I didn't forget anything.

Comment: *"I know that this can do that for one row, but I need all rows..."* What do you mean? The `apply(...)` command you give generates a *vector* of concatenated column entries *for every row*. Also, `table` is a poor name for a user variable, as it masks the base R function `table`. Lastly, I'm entirely not clear on how your expected output is supposed to look. Can you edit your post to include your expected output for the sample data you give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a look up list, loop through rows using *apply*, subset by name, then paste with *toString*:

```
# make a lookup list
lookUP <- list(A = c("orderedNr", "TextA", "TextB", "Year", "Date"),
               B = c("orderedNr", "TextB", "TextA", "Year", "Date"),
               C = c("orderedNr", "Year", "TextB", "TextA", "Date"))

# loop through rows, subset column in certain order, then paste
example$newColumn <- 
  apply(example, 1, function(i) toString(i[ lookUP[[ i["Type"] ]] ]))


# result
example
# Nr orderedNr Type  TextA  TextB Year       Date                            newColumn
# 1  469         1    A  Text2 Text12 2012 01.01.2015   1, Text2, Text12, 2012, 01.01.2015
# 2  470         8    C  Text9 Text19 1961 08.01.2015   8, 1961, Text19, Text9, 08.01.2015
# 3  471         2    A  Text3 Text13 2012 02.01.2015   2, Text3, Text13, 2012, 02.01.2015
# 4  472         9    C Text10 Text20 1947 09.01.2015  9, 1947, Text20, Text10, 09.01.2015
# 5  474         3    B  Text4 Text14 2005 03.01.2015   3, Text14, Text4, 2005, 03.01.2015
# 6  622         5    A  Text6 Text16 1993 05.01.2015   5, Text6, Text16, 1993, 05.01.2015
# 7  623         6    B  Text7 Text17 2009 06.01.2015   6, Text17, Text7, 2009, 06.01.2015
# 8  624         7    B  Text8 Text18 1964 07.01.2015   7, Text18, Text8, 1964, 07.01.2015
# 9  625         4    C  Text5 Text15 2009 04.01.2015   4, 2009, Text15, Text5, 04.01.2015
# 10 626        10    A Text11 Text21 1988 10.01.2015 10, Text11, Text21, 1988, 10.01.2015
```

Comment: With `example <- example[order(example$orderedNr),]` in between it works perfectly! I like the `lookUP` list, because I don't yet know how many types I will have. Afterwards I can print using `outstring <- paste(example$newColumn)` and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility using functions from the tidyverse.

```
require(tidyverse)
example %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(
        col1 = orderedNr,
        col2 = case_when(
            Type == "A" ~ TextA,
            Type == "B" ~ TextB,
            Type == "C" ~ as.character(Year)),
        col3 = case_when(
            Type == "A" | Type == "C" ~ TextB,
            Type == "B" ~ TextA),
        col4 = case_when(
            Type == "A" | Type == "B" ~ as.character(Year),
            Type == "C" ~ TextA),
        col5 = Date) %>%
    select(contains("col")) %>%
    arrange(col5)
#    col1   col2   col3   col4       col5
# 1     1  Text2 Text12   2012 01.01.2015
# 2     2  Text3 Text13   2012 02.01.2015
# 3     3 Text14  Text4   2005 03.01.2015
# 4     4   2009 Text15  Text5 04.01.2015
# 5     5  Text6 Text16   1993 05.01.2015
# 6     6 Text17  Text7   2009 06.01.2015
# 7     7 Text18  Text8   1964 07.01.2015
# 8     8   1961 Text19  Text9 08.01.2015
# 9     9   1947 Text20 Text10 09.01.2015
# 10   10 Text11 Text21   1988 10.01.2015
```